# store a json to a variable swift3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

```
{
    "schedule": [
    {
    "day": "Sunday",
    "events": [
    {
    "show_id": "00000",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "00030",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "00100",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"
    },
    {
    "show_id": "00130",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "00200",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "00300",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "00400",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "00500",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "day": "Monday",
    "events": [
    {
    "show_id": "00600",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "00730",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "00800",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "00930",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "01200",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "01300",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "01400",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "01500",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "day": "Tuesday",
    "events": [
    {
    "show_id": "01600",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "01730",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "01800",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "01930",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00",

    },
    {
    "show_id": "02000",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "02100",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "02200",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "02300",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "day": "Wednesday",
    "events": [
    {
    "show_id": "02400",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "02530",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"
    },
    {
    "show_id": "02600",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "02730",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "02800",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00",
    "show_title": "Talk Show"
    },
    {
    "show_id": "02900",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "03000",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "03100",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "day": "Thursday",
    "events": [
    {
    "show_id": "04000",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "04130",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "04200",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "04330",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "04400",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "04500",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "04600",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "04700",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "day": "Friday",
    "events": [
    {
    "show_id": "04800",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "04930",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "05000",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "02:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "05130",
    "show_time": "02:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "05230",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "05300",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "05400",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "05500",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "05600",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    }
    ]
    },
    {
    "day": "Saturday",
    "events": [
    {
    "show_id": "05700",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "05830",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "05900",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "06030",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00",

    },
    {
    "show_id": "06100",
    "show_time": "06:00",
    "show_time_end": "09:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "06200",
    "show_time": "09:00",
    "show_time_end": "12:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "06300",
    "show_time": "12:00",
    "show_time_end": "03:00"

    },
    {
    "show_id": "06400",
    "show_time": "03:00",
    "show_time_end": "06:00"

    }
    ]
    }
    ]
  }
```

This is not the output of any API calls. I typed this in the form of a json response.. I want to store this JSON to a variable and use it in my programme. I hav tried many ways. But i am getting errors. I want to store this to a variable and retrieve each details one by one to a string array.
Can anyone help me please. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of errors? Please be more specific and share the error details.

Comment: I tried var v = myJSON.. I dont know if its the right way

Answer (score 1):

The last elements in an array shouldn't be trailed by a ','.

```
    "show_time_end": "09:00",
```

should be

```
    "show_time_end": "09:00"
```

To load the example within code:

```
let data = "string here".data(using: .utf8); 
let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],
let schedule = json["schedule"]
```

Comment: Ok ,revised comment for error in last item in sequence list

Comment: That too was a typing mistake. Its not about the format .I want to store this in a variable. Like we use to store a string to a variable.(for example var s = mystring)

Comment: Thanks brother. But that example is for a JSON output or response. This is not a JSON response. I want to type like this and store in a variable. like var v = above mentioned JSON

Comment: let data = "string here".data(using: .utf8); let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],

Comment: I think in order to help you please explain exactly what you need. JSON is normally loaded from a file or network. What’s your end goal here. Do you need to use a class or a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the json as .json file in your project then you should try this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "yourfilename", ofType: "json") {
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
    do{
        let json =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
// you can use the json object now
}
```